# python - Return value in different functions

Tags: python, count

I am working on a Roomba robot (cleaning robot) and I have to print each time the robot bumps into something. I also have to take pictures every 10 seconds thanks to the Picamera. I would like to be able to print that a bump happens between pictures n and pictures n+1.
When a picture is taken, I increment the number of pictures taken and the same when a bump happens (increment the number of bumps). 
For example, if bump 1 appears between pictures number 1 and 2, my code will print "Bump 1 between pictures 1 and picture 2". 
The problem is that if picture 2 is taken, my code will print "Bump 1 between picture 2 and picture 3". But it is false, Bump 1 is still between picture 1 and picture 2.
I can't find a solution to be able to stay between the same pictures even if a another one has been taken.

```
count = 0
PicturesNumber = 0

def takePictures():

global PicturesNumber

    for i in range(10):
        sleep(5)
        PicturesNumber += 1
        print(("Picture %i taken" % (i + 1,)))
        camera.capture(('/home/pi/Project/image%s.jpg') % (i,))
        camera.close()
    return PicturesNumber

def reactSensors():

    global count
    threading.Timer(1, reactSensors).start()
    array = r.getSensor('BUMPS_AND_WHEEL_DROPS') # get information from the roomba sensors
    if array[3] == 1 or array[4] == 1:
       count += 1
       #print(("Bump %i" % (count,)))
    return count

def displayBumpings():

    threading.Timer(1, displayBumpings).start()
    print(("Bump %i between picture %i and picture %i\n" (count + 1, PicturesNumber, PicturesNumber + 1,)))

 if __name__ == '__main__':

 r = create.Create(SERIAL_PORT)
 settime = time.time()

 resp = input("Ready to roll? ")
 if resp[0] != 'y':
 r.shutdown()
 if resp[0] == 'y':
 print("Let's go\n")

 # I am using threading to run each function at the same time
 Thread(target=reactSensors).start()
 Thread(target=takePictures).start()
 Thread(target=displayBumpings).start()
```

I know that there is a problem with the DisplayBumpings print line because PicturesNumber updates is value each time a picture is taken.

This is what I get in the shell

```
Picture 1 taken

Bump 1 between picture 1 and picture 2

Picture 2 taken

Bump 1 between picture 2 and picture 3
```

Thank you very much for any answer !

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable that is only updated when count is? 
What I mean is, in reactSensor():

```
reactSensor(): 
   ... 
   if array[3] == 1 or array[4] == 1: 
     count +=1 
     newvariable = PicturesNumber
     global newvariable

def displayBumpings():

    threading.Timer(1, displayBumpings).start()
    print(("Bump %i between picture %i and picture %i\n" (count + 1,newvariable, newvariable+ 1,)))
```

and then you use newvariable when bumping.

Comment: I tried this and It didn't work.
I would like something like "if bump count doesn't change, still print that the last bump happened between picture n and picture n+1, even if 1000 pictures have been taken".

Comment: Ah, yes. Ignore what I wrote, you don't even modify the count value in displayBumpings(), sorry. I cant test your code on my machine, but I've read it several times and it seems it should work? According to what you say you get in the shell it is correct, no?
Could you specify more exactly what the problem is?

Comment: What I get in the shell is correct until Picture 2 is taken. As you can see, picture 2 is taken. But then, bump 1, that truly appeared between picture 1 and picture 2, is now appearing between picture 2 and picture 3. But it is the same bump, it should print :

`Picture 2 taken`

`Bump 1 between picture 1 and picture 2`

Comment: Add a variable that is only updated when count is?

What I mean is, in reactSensor():

reactSensor():
   ...
   if array[3] == 1 or array[4] == 1:
      count +=1
      newvariable = PicturesNumber

and then you use newvariable when bumping.

Comment: gosh that got cluttery, will update main answer with this

Comment: I get the trick. But for some reason I have the error : name 'newvariable' is not defined

Comment: Declare the variable in the beginning like you did count and PictureNumber, I think

Comment: Awesome, no problem!